# lsyncd + rsync の同期設定でエラー

Tags: ssh, lsyncd, rsync

[`lsyncd`](https://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/) と `rsync` を使って２つのサーバーのミラーリングを設定しているのですが、 `lsyncd` 自体はちゃんと動いていて同期をしようとしているのですが、ログを見ると以下のエラーで同期ができなくなっております。`rsync` の設定がおかしいのかなといろいろ設定しなおしているのですが、全く改善しておりません。

設定は、コピー元に `lsyncd` + `rsync` を入れて、同期先に `rsync` を入れています。 OS は CentOS 6 です。

```
@ERROR: chroot failed
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1503) [sender=3.0.6]
Wed Feb  4 10:27:09 2015 Normal: Retrying startup of "/home/use/test
```

むかし２〜３回設定したぐらいでいろいろと忘れており何かしら設定を忘れているのかもしれないです。

詳しい方ご教授いただければ幸いです。  
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: こちら [rsync SERVER fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267507/rsync-server-fails) が参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: 参考資料、ありがとうございます。
use chroot = false
で@ERROR: chroot failedはなくなったのですが、今現在@ERROR chdir failedに悩まされております。以前として格闘中です。

Comment: chdir に失敗するということは、同期先のディレクトリにパーミッション（`x`）が付いていない可能性がありますね。それと、chdir の問題を質問欄に追記しておくと新しい回答が得られるかもしれません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267507/rsync-server-fails
ここに同様の問いがあるのですが、
rsyncの設定ファイルrsyncd.confに
use chroot = (true/false)
を環境に合わせて編集か追記でいけるんじゃないでしょか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。頂いたやり方でやってみました。
@ERROR: chroot failedのかわりに今度は、@ERROR chdir failedが出てきて格闘中です。

Comment: 何とかいろいろやってみて何とか動くようにはなりました。結局何が原因だったのかわからない感じでしたが。。。皆様いろいろありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

今さらですが、SELINUXがじゃましてました。私の場合